# Exhaust smell after transmission replacement

Tags: transmission, exhaust

Backstory: I took my car in for a transmission fluid change.

Current problem: 4 months later I smell a burning/exhaust smell when I drive my car. It’s okay for extremely short distances, but the more I drive it the worse it gets. I had a mechanic open the hood and check it for leaks and he couldn’t find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a burnt clutch or bad torque converter.